# TFS 2012 build changeset version in PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfsbuild

We have a TFS 2012 instance and a build agent w/ VS 2017.  I am trying to modify a XAML build template to create a nuget package from a given project.  I am required to put the changeset number in the description of the package but I am unable to get the correct value.

I have an InvokeProcess activity in the AgentScope of my template which runs a PowerShell script to pack the package.  I have tried getting the TF_BUILD_* environment variables but none seem to be populated.  I also tried BUILD_SOURCEVERSION with no luck.  At the moment I am passing in the BuildDetail.SourceGetVersion value but that is returning the current changeset for the entire team project, not the specific project I am building.

What am I doing wrong?  Are those variables only on the TFS server and not on the agent (build server)?

Answer (score 1):

> TFS 2012 build changeset version in PowerShell script

According to the article [Build Script Hooks for TFS 2012 Builds](https://www.colinsalmcorner.com/post/build-script-hooks-for-tfs-2012-builds):

> When I created a script for a 2013 build to version the assemblies, I
>   relied on the fact that the 2013 build sets some environment variables
>   that you can use in your scripts.You can see I’m getting
>   $env:TF_BUILD_BUILDNUMBER. Well, **in the 2012 workflow, these variables
>   aren’t set, so you have to add an activity to do it**.

That the reason why you tried getting the TF_BUILD_* environment variables but none seem to be populated.

So, to resolve this issue, you can just to follow the steps in Challenge 2 to set it.

Or, you can use TFS API to get the latest changeset number in your TFS version control:

Please see this thread for detailed information:

[Programmatically retrieve the latest changeset number available in a workspace](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ab50a59b-4cc9-4659-87c8-94ed7744c78c/programmatically-retrieve-the-latest-changeset-number-available-in-a-workspace?forum=tfsversioncontrol)

Then you can write another small program to modify your description field in the `.cs` file be the changeset number you get in above.

Hope this helps.